# Make all combinations two digit from single string

Tags: vb.net

I have a Textbox1.Text like that: `1784397425`

How can I get the 2 combinations or 1 combination out of here?

this is a model:

Like `17 78 84 43 39 97 74 42 25 1 7 8 4 3 9 7 4 2 5`

That's another model:

It can also be like this: (first digit 1, we take 1 by 7, then 1 by 8 and so on.)

```
17 18 14 13 19 17 14 15
```

and so on...

```
78 74 73 79 77 74 72 75
84 83 89 87 84 82 85
43 49 47 44 42 45
39 37 34 32 35
and so on...
```

any such model algorithm would help me a lot either of these two.

Code 3: unfortunately this doesn't work very well.

```
Since they're strings to begin with you can use.
Left(str,n) n is the number of left characters you want.
Right(str,n) n is the number of Right characters you want.
Mid(str,n,nn) Mid is like substring where n is the starting char, and nn is the number from start you want from the str.

Dim line1 = "47"

Dim d1 As String = Left(line1,1)   'this is 4

Dim d2 As String = Right(line1,1)  'this is 7

now the math

Dim a1 As Integer = Int(d1) + Int(d2)

or 

Dim a1 As Integer = CInt(d1) + CInt(d2)
```

Comment: *"any such model algorithm would help me a lot either of these two."* It's up to you to come up with the algorithm first, then write code to implement that algorithm. What steps would you perform to do this manually, with pen and paper? That's not a programming question so no programming experience required. It's a logic question so you just have to be prepared to apply some effort and brain power to the problem. Once you have the algorithm, then you can try to write code to implement it. If something doesn't work at that stage, then you've got a question to ask here.

Comment: Look below, the code is put.

Comment: "the code" is pretty much rubbish. What algorithm is it supposed to be implementing? *"this doesn't work very well"* is not a description of a problem.

Comment: I should do the implementation for any set of numbers, the problem I have is like this: without commas like 12,78,43,56 and related like 12784356 so he has to go worked on 12784356

Comment: What you want is all the [SubString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_)s of length 2 (and those of length 1), not combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Andrew, use [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) to extract the portion of the string that you want.

I've wrapped that in an iterator that returns all the substrings:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox2.Text = String.Join(" ", Substrings(TextBox1.Text, 2))
End Sub

Public Iterator Function Substrings(ByVal source As String, ByVal length As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    If length >= 1 AndAlso length <= source.Length Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To (source.Length - length)
            Yield source.Substring(i, length)
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

If you want the user to set the value of the length parameter, then drop a [NumericUpDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=netcore-3.1) control on your form and grab the `.Value` from that.